# android: dynamic getString(R.string.report_TJ) for strings.xml

Tags: android, string, variables

I am sorry for the subject, but I do not know how to match my question.

In my strings.xml I have different languages eg

```
getString(R.string.report_TJ)
```

and I get json data with

```
e.getString("artID")
```

but I need something like this:

```
getString(R.string.report_TJ_1)
```

you see, at the end 1. artID = 1

How can I do it?

I try it like this:

```
try{
    //String text = getString(R.string.report_TJ);
    JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("uTraf");
    mylist.clear();
    String report_TJ_btn = null;
            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                String imageString=report_TJ_btn+e.getString("artID");

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("first", getString(getResources().getIdentifier(imageString, "", getPackageName())) + "Stau: " + e.getString("road") + ", " + e.getString("county"));
                map.put("second", e.getString("timestamp") + ", " + e.getString("suburb"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
  }
```

with this error:
11-29 10:40:08.544: W/ResourceType(487): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```
String imageString=report_TJ_+e.getString("artID");
getString(getResources().getIdentifier(imageString, "", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: can you help me to bring it together with my example?

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem can you help me again?